# Why use the UUID method over traditional ID?

Tags: privacy, databases

The following quote came from one of my Teachers not to long ago, along with an exercise to build an application:

> To follow guidelines, you are to use UUID's instead of ID's.

Of course, the question *Why is an UUID safer/better than an traditional ID* came by.

The UUID is supposed to be used in a Database table of Users, containing login, but also personal information like phone number, real name, address etc.

From what I know, it's written in a few enterprise guidelines for larger companies to utilize UUID's when working with privacy sensitive information, *Is it also custom to apply an UUID to other information other than privacy sensitive information?*

Comment: What was the UUID used for?

Comment: Please describe the context

Comment: @Jay Described the context better, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WoJ has addressed the security aspect, I'm going to add why it may be a bad idea to use a UUID as an ID.

There are a few potential gotchas with using a UUID as a PK on a table.

- UUIDs take up more space than ints
- UUIDs are slower to join on than ints

There is also an issue with the clustering key on the table being a UUID - check the accepted answer on this question for a good explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega

Comment: The exact opposite of the answer I was excpeting, but still a very good one.

Answer (score 3):

A [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) will not add any specific security when used as an ID in a database. Its main role is to be (reasonably) unique.

Basing the security of a database on the randomness of IDs (supposedly because they are harder to guess than an incremental ID, I guess) is not a good security measure. It will certainly not hurt but the [basic mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_security) must be applied first. What is of uttermost importance is the security of the application requesting data from this database (SQL Injection being one of the top concerns)